# does c++11 programs work on any CPU?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, processor

note:before down vote or anything like this,this is a general question to understand more how everything is going

the question simply is:
assume I compiled a program with c++11 features (using VS2012 on windows) is there a guarantee that this program will run on older processors?(like core 2 duo;as most laptops got this)

I'm currently working with VS2010,but found libraries that needs C++11 features.
so I want to port the whole work to VS2012,but my knowledge is limited about how this gonna work

correct anything wrong in the question

edit:
another 2 questions:

1  -can I "mix" a compiled c++11 program with older one?

like calling functions which are inside the new version (.dll) from an old version(.exe)     so I got 2 files:

1 is compiled with VS2010 the other 1 is compiled with VS2012,with DLL EXPORT can they work like that?

2   -suggest a better environment than VS2012 for windows

Comment: This is not a language issue.  It depends on what the compiler target is.

Comment: Before you just jump in head first, make sure VS has implemented the features you're porting for. VS is a bit more conservative, or possibly just slower, than others and do not have everything available yet. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).

Comment: Question #2 should be avoided. You're only going to get opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The compiler requires additional libraries to build the program. But this shouldn't affect the ability to run on older processors. The only time this changes is when your trying to run a 64 bit program on a 32 bit processor.

Porting to VS2012 is simple, open the solution in VS2012, and save it as a vs2012 solution. It should all be fine.

Edit: odds are, if your new to programming, all of your programs are compiled for 32 bit processors by default unless you code to change this, so you shouldn't worry. You can run 32 bit programs on 64 bit processors, just not the other way around. If you really want to step it up, you can make a program that can run on both processors ;)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the architecture for which the target is built is the same (x86 for 32 bits or amd64 for 64 bits) you shouldn't have any issue.

Of course you will need to provide the older machine with the correct runtime library to run your program (for the current architecture).

Comment: While it's specific to C++11, there are of course differences within x86 that you need to be aware of. For example, `cmov` support.

Answer (score 0):

given a compiled executable the usual requirements to run it are:

- ABI
- platform
- libraries

and since Windows is a commercial product, depending on what are you doing, you could add another factor

- environment

which means that sometimes a software house intentionally breaks the compatibility with other products to sell more stuff.

In general VS it's not that good, certainly it's not the best the compiler I have ever used and basically anything from GCC to Clang to MinGW can supersede VS easily, but VS it's the official compiler and environment for Windows so this is what you have to deal with most of the time.

If you have fulfilled the listed requirements you are good to go.

By the way a Core 2 Duo it's not that old, and the actual iCore generation it's not that different either.